# Problems with strip function in generating list of lists

Tags: list, strip

I'm having a slight problem with this function. I'm trying to generate a list of lists. For each item in those lists I need to remove the space to the left and to the right of each item. For some reason it's only working for the first item in each list.

```
def filereadlistoflists():
master_list=[]
input_file = open('movies.txt','r')
for line in input_file:
    add_line = line.strip().split(",")
    master_list.append(add_line)


return master_list
```

Here's the result:

```
[['Brad Pitt', ' Sleepers', ' Troy', ' Meet Joe Black', ' Oceans Eleven', ' Seven', ' Mr & Mrs Smith'], ['Tom Hanks', ' You have got mail', ' Apollo 13', ' Sleepless in Seattle', ' Catch Me If You Can']
```